# Css3 animation doesn't work in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css-animations, internet-explorer-11

Hi I have this animation. It works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari but not in IE 11. Could you please tell me where is problem? I can't find why it doesn't work in IE. As I read IE11 should work with css transforms just fine.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.box div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.rotateDoorsLeft {
  animation: rotateDoorsLeft .75s infinite ease 0s alternate;
  -webkit-animation: rotateDoorsLeft .75s infinite ease 0s alternate;
  -moz-animation: rotateDoorsLeft .75s infinite ease 0s alternate;
  -ms-animation: rotateDoorsLeft .75s infinite ease 0s alternate;
}
.rotateDoorsRight {
  animation: rotateDoorsRight .75s infinite ease 0s alternate;
  -webkit-animation: rotateDoorsRight .75s infinite ease 0s alternate;
  -moz-animation: rotateDoorsRight .75s infinite ease 0s alternate;
  -ms-animation: rotateDoorsRight .75s infinite ease 0s alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateDoorsLeft {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(360) rotateY(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(360) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateDoorsRight {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(360) rotateY(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(360) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateDoorsLeft {
  from {
    -moz-transform: perspective(360) rotateY(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: perspective(360) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateDoorsRight {
  from {
    -moz-transform: perspective(360) rotateY(-90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: perspective(360) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  }
}
@keyframes rotateDoorsLeft {
  from {
    transform: perspective(360) rotateY(90deg);
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  }
  to {
    transform: perspective(360) rotateY(0deg);
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  }
}
@keyframes rotateDoorsRight {
  from {
    transform: perspective(360) rotateY(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  }
  to {
    transform: perspective(360) rotateY(0deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateDoorsLeft {
  from {
    -ms-transform: perspective(360) rotateY(90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: perspective(360) rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateDoorsRight {
  from {
    -ms-transform: perspective(360) rotateY(-90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: perspective(360) rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="left-box rotateDoorsLeft"></div>
  <div class="right-box rotateDoorsRight"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are supposed to put the code without the prefix last, move it to the bottom, thats why it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a unit to the `perspective(360)` values. For instance, `perspective(360px)`.

From [the Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#funcdef-perspective):

```
perspective() = perspective( <length> )
```

The definition of a [*length*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#length-value) is "*...a number immediately followed by a unit identifier.*" As such, in providing a positive non-zero number without a unit is invalid, and therefore doesn't give you the desired results in a standards-compliant browser.

Comment: thanks, worked like charm, I didn't think that that could be error when it worked in other browsers

Comment: Always check the spec in cases like this; IE was just following the rules :) Note: I work on the IE team.